# How can we obtain date time format in yyyy.MM.dd

Tags: c#, date, time

How can we obtain the current date in format `yyyy.MM.dd` in C# ASP.NET?

using DateTime.Now

Comment: you want that as string right ?

Comment: We want it in date time.

Comment: @BinodBajracharya `Datetime` is datetime, it is string which can be formated, not `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by using

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
```

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for more info on custom date and time formats.